# "Inverse" and "Converse" in academic writing

Tags: word-usage

Do the words "inverse" and the words "converse" have the same meaning in academic writing as they do as logic terms? Or would it cause confusion?

If I write, "conversely...", will it mean that whatever I proceed to discuss involves a switching of cause-and-effect roles, different from the previous topic?

If I write, "inversely...", will it mean that an effect does not happen because the cause does not happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *OED* gives the sense of reversed or opposite for both *converse* and *inverse* as well as defining the adverbs with "in the manner" of their associated adjectives.  But the two cannot be used interchangeably.  In situations in which terms are exchanged, you must use *conversely*:

> All squares are rectangles, but **conversely**, not all rectangles are
>   squares.

*Inversely* is the choice when you're talking about a turnabout in position:

> The sculpture was an **inversely** situated cone.

That is, the sculpture has the base above the apex.  The same is true for expressing a reversed proportionality:

> The length of the sentences of the convicted were **inversely**
>   related to their income.

That is, the more money you have, the less time you spend in jail.

(Obviously, the two words are also not equivalents in technical mathematical usage, e.g., in logic and algebra.)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying those definitions. If, however, there was a situation where I wanted to use the meaning of "inverse" in logic, i.e. "This condition was NOT met, so this effect did NOT happen," what equivalent word would I use in other contexts? Literature analysis, for example.

Comment: @Cameron If you're writing academic lit-crit, you may use your own private language.  That said, given the proposition "If p, then q", the statement "If not p, then not q" is the inverse.  The converse switches p and q: "If q, then p."  Neither is logically equivalent to the original.

Comment: But the [contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition), which is the converse of the inverse (or the inverse of the converse -- they commute), **is** logically equivalent to the original. "If p, then q" is equivalent to "If not q, then not p". If it's raining, you get wet; if you don't get wet, it isn't raining.